# StageOrientationEvent is not dispatching in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

i have this code from the adobe forum, which works on the first screen of a mobile application. But it doesnt work if i put this code in a new view ( in a view which i have pushed )
Does anybody know the solution to this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView" creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.*;
            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage)
            }
            private function _onAddedToStage(event:Event):void{
                if(stage.autoOrients)                    stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, _onStage_OrientationChange);
            }
            private function _onStage_OrientationChange(event:StageOrientationEvent):void{
    switch(event.afterOrientation){
                    case StageOrientation.DEFAULT:
                        trace('DEFAULT')
                        break;
                    case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT:
                        trace('ROTATED_RIGHT');
                        break;
                    case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT:
                        trace('ROTATED_LEFT');
                        break;
                    case StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN:
                        trace('UPSIDE_DOWN');
                        break;
                    case StageOrientation.UNKNOWN:
                        trace('UNKNOWN');
                        break;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script> 
</s:View>
```

Comment: The following APIs are available only in AIR applications on mobile devices

Comment: How can i dispatch an Event, if  the device is rotated then?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{

        if(stage.autoOrients)       

        stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, _onStage_OrientationChange);

    }
```

Comment: As i said. The Code works!! But the problem is NOT in a pushed view!